# Prove that a power series$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ which is convergent for any $ z \in \Bbb N$, converges for any $z \in \Bbb C$.

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

Proof:

The power series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$$ which converges for any $ z \in 
 \Bbb N$, then the series converges absolutely for ay $z_0$ s.t. $|z_0|<|z|$.

Let $z_\alpha \in \Bbb C$, $\forall$ $z_\alpha$, $\exists z \in \Bbb N$ s.t. $|z_\alpha|<|z|$. Since the series converges for any $z \in \Bbb N$, using the proposition above, the series converges absolutely for any $z_\alpha \in \Bbb C$.

Question.

I am not totally sure about my proof, is correct or not? If not, how can i improved it?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Ethan, I already saw that but somehow I kinda change my approach. What do you think?

Comment: Your proof is correct. If I were writing it I'd replace the logical symbols by words.

Comment: Thanks @EthanBolker. Your comment is of great relief.